# "Advanced Custome Fields" plugin errors

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I would appreciate a lot help on this. After I tried to edit a "single page" (Elementor) the draws content from Advanced Custom Fields field, I started getting this error :
[image]

It turned out the problem is linked to the plugin ACF:
[image].

I tried disabling it. When I did, the error disappeared, but I started getting a new one!
[image]

Many thanks in advanced for the help. I am not a developer and the issue seems too complex for my level of expertise.

Mourad

Comment: Please re-enable ACF and [turn on debugging](https://wpforms.com/developers/how-to-enable-debugging-in-wordpress/). We need to see what the original "critical error" is ....

Comment: Re-install both ACF and Elementor.

Comment: @Jamie_D Thanks a lot for the reply. I did as suggested, but I can't find a way to post the error message; it is too long.

Comment: @Jamie_D, how do I post the error message?! (First time using this forum)

Comment: @Jamie_D, I don't know if this link to the error message will work : https://freedom4tunisia.com/rights_violators/mourad-hassine/?preview_id=7730&preview_nonce=97e327d447&preview=true